# How to update rows in a table based on a range from two rows in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm working on researching this myself but I wanted to get some input from the community in the meantime. I have a SQL Server 2012 database with a couple of tables like so:

**DISCOUNT**

```
Id    Quantity    DiscountAmount
--------------------------------
1     500         6
2     1000        8
3     1500        10
```

I have another table called `Reviews` with thousands of entries in it. The schema of that table is not important.

What I want to do is loop through the entries in the `Discounts` table and apply an `UPDATE` statement to all of the records in the `Reviews` table where the row number of that review falls between the current Discount row's quantity and the next quantity - 1.

So in pseudo-code:

```
For each row in the discount table order by quantity asc
BEGIN    
    UPDATE Review SET Discount=DiscountAmount WHERE [ROW NUMBER]
    BETWEEN Quantity[CURRENT_ROW] AND Quantity[NEXT_ROW]-1
END
```

Effectively this sets the discount amount for the first 499 rows to 0 (which is the default for Discount), then for 500-999 they get a discount of 6, for 1000-1499 they get a discount of 8 and for 1500+ they get a discount of 10.

Comment: Set up http://www.sqlfiddle.com and you will get answer quicker. Second thing why do you want to do CURSOR like processing in SQL. Change thinking to SET based.

Comment: I'm fine with a set based answer, just looking for solutions to the given problem, regardless of what approach they take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using simple MAX:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78381/2)**

```
/* Preparing data */
CREATE TABLE Review(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), val INT, discount INT NULL);

INSERT INTO Review(val)
VALUES (12), (400), (600), (1100), (1550);

CREATE TABLE Discount(Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Quantity INT, DiscountAmount INT);

INSERT INTO Discount(Quantity, DiscountAmount)
VALUES (500, 6), (1000, 8), (1500, 10);


/* Main */
UPDATE rev
SET Discount = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(d.DiscountAmount), 0) 
                FROM Discount d
                WHERE rev.val >= d.Quantity)
FROM Review rev;
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: @jpw Do you see code, there is >=, only not in fiddle.

Comment: @jpw Fiddle doesn't want to cooperate with me and change this ;(

Answer (score 1):

If you have only 4 tiers for discount you can simply write an update statement with a case expression in it.

```
UPDATE Review 
 SET Discount = CASE 
                     WHEN Quantity < 500 THEN 0
                     WHEN Quantity >= 500 AND Quantity <= 999 THEN 6
                     WHEN Quantity >= 1000 AND Quantity <= 1499 THEN 8
                     WHEN Quantity >= 1500 THEN 10
                END
```

Comment: This needs to be driven by another table in the use case I described. The example I gave above is simplified for the SO audience.